# 'Expected class or package' when using Intents and OnClickListeners

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have this weird problem which only occurs on this one activity and I cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

Ther errors are coming up at "notReg.OnClickListener..." and "registerBtn.OnCLickListener..."

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final TextView notReg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notReg);
        final Button registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

        notReg.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(register.this, login.class);
                register.this.startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        });

        registerBtn.OnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(register.this, home.class);
                register.this.startActivity(homeIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set event `Click` on `Button`,  try `setOnClickListener` instead of `OnClickListener`

```
notReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(register.this, login.class);
            register.this.startActivity(loginIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow, Didn't even see that! Thanks so much. It's almost 3 am. Probably not helping myself!